# Use SVG in Windows Azure Websites

Tags: iis, azure, svg, azure-web-app-service

Does anyone know if it is possible to add the SVG mime type to a Windows Azure Website?
I tried with a web.config file but that only broke my website.

Is this a limitation of the current preview or am I missing something?

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 105, accepted):

What you can do in Windows Azure Websites (on web.config level) is pretty limited, but you [should](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2012/07/09/Tweaking-Windows-Azure-Web-Sites.aspx) be allowed to add the mime type under **staticContent**:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
         <remove fileExtension=".svg"/>
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
      </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This works! I already tried something like this before but I guess I did it wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @SnippetSpace - I've had the experience where adding a `<mimeMap />` to an Azure website that the Azure web server already supports can break the website. That might be what you ran into before.

Comment: It's important to remove the existing registration first to have it work local. Like the example here http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/08/07/configuration-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-4-on-a-windows.aspx

Comment: I had to add a `<remove fileExtension=".svg"/>` *before* the `<mimeType />` to make it work on my machine.

Comment: I wasn't able to find this anywhere, but you can simply put file a called `web.config` in the root of your repository with the content shown above. Then `.svg`-files should work – it did on my Azure Web App.

Comment: Works as expected. Big relief after updateing my webapp and seeing it didn't get the .svg file with a 404 altough it was published, phew...thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Others like me may have reached here having the same problem not resolved because of other related file types, in my case I also needed `.eot` and `.woff` mime mappings.

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
        <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
        <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"  />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did following the new icon standards that you need these days from using https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#font

```
<staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
    <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
    <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
    <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"  />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
</staticContent>
```