# None of the SVG on Azure remedies have worked for me

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, svg

The approach outlined in these posts has not worked for me:

-Use SVG in Windows Azure Websites: ([Use SVG in Windows Azure Websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846689/use-svg-in-windows-azure-websites))

-The Usual HTML 5 Media Types: (http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/08/07/configuration-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-4-on-a-windows.aspx)

-ASP.NET enable SVG images Azure, to be put in system.webServer: (https://gist.github.com/kyranjamie/5104476)

Specifically I have purchased a video player product and its control bar uses svg to draw its assets, play/pause/rewind/FF/full screen buttons, etc.  I've deployed the player to other servers and the controls render.  I get that the type is simply not defined on my Azure server and needs to be.  How do I do that?

My project is an ASP.NET MVC 4 app via VS 2012.  If you have suggestions they would be appreciated. Those above have made no impact for me.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".mp4"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".ogv"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".webm"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".svg"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"/>
    </staticContent>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>    
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: What does your web.config look like?

Comment: I take it you mean the system.webServer section?  I added above.

Comment: Looks the same as what I've got, I would expect that to work.

Comment: The <staticContent> section worked for me.

Comment: Double checked it has deployed correctly? Worked when I used it a few months back.

Comment: I've done what you're trying to do before and the staticContent bit is the way to go. What is your exact error?