# Unable to Publish .SVG File to Azure Website

Tags: azure, svg, web-config, mime

I have an .svg file located in my Microsoft Azure `"~/css/fonts/"` directory. When I publish the site, all the css and eot files get published, by my one and only .svg file does not.

I've read [other SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846689/use-svg-in-windows-azure-websites) that mentioned that we have to explicitly add `mimeMaps` to the `web.config`, so I've updated/Published my `web.config` with the following:

```
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
       <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
       <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
       <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
       <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"  />
       <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
       <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

... and then re-Published the specific .svg file, but I get the following error:

```
Preparing to publish files...
Using ID 'dc2a......' for connections to the remote server.
Using ID 'a2c7......' for connections to the remote server.
Using ID '9720......' for connections to the remote server.
Using ID 'aff7......' for connections to the remote server.
Using ID '4d1d......' for connections to the remote server.
The synchronization is being stopped because the maximum number of sync passes '5' has been exceeded even though all the changes could not be applied. This could occur if there are external changes being made to the destination.
```

The error above only occurs when I try to upload the .svg file (all other file types that I have do not throw this error.)

Is there anything else that I need to do to publish my .svg file?

Note: I'm using VS2013 Pro to Publish my site to Windows Azure.

Comment: How are you publishing?  From what app/source?

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 Pro

Comment: Right click on the svg file in Visual Studio and select properties, then check that "Build Action" is set to "Content"

Comment: And another question - ftp deployment, or via "Publish"?

Comment: I checked the "Build Action" and it is set for "Content". I upload the site via "Publish".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made the mistake of adding the `<staticContent>` to the `web.config` located in the `Views` folder (in my MVC5 proj) instead of placing the `<staticContent>` in the `Web.config` file that is located in the root of my project. :\

Once I moved the content to the correct .config, my .svg is now getting Published.