# Can't get SVG served from Azure

Tags: azure, svg, web-config

I'm building a static HTML5 web site on VS2014 and deploying via Dropbox to be hosted on Azure. All works using F5 on VS2014. But my SVG images do not get served from Azure. I get HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found errors. I have tried this solution:
[Use SVG in Windows Azure Websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846689/use-svg-in-windows-azure-websites/11846971#11846971) and the code snippet suggested by Mads Kristensen at http://madskristensen.net/post/prepare-webconfig-for-html5-and-css3. My web.Debug.config & web.Release.config files are both as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".svg"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

Here's the question. What should I do to get my svg files to download?

EDIT: I found the problem. As a relative new user of VS2014 and Azure, I overlooked the higher level Web.config file and only worked with the lower two files mentioned above. Putting the additional staticContent lines into the Web.config file fixed everything.

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem. As a relative new user of VS2014 and Azure, I overlooked the higher level Web.config file and only worked with the lower two files mentioned above. Putting the additional staticContent lines into the Web.config file fixed everything.